# How to get a flattened view of PyTorch model parameters?

Tags: python, memory, parameters, pytorch, neural-network

I want to have a flattened view of the parameters belonging to my Pytorch model. Note it should be a **view** and not a copy of the parameters. In other words, when I modify the parameters in the view it should also modify the model parameter. I can get the model parameters as follows:

```py
import torch

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(1, 10), 
    torch.nn.Tanh(), 
    torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)
)

params = list(model.parameters())

for p in params:
    print(p)
```

Here `params` is a list of tensors. I need it to be a 1D tensor of all the parameter instead. It is trivial to do

```py
params = torch.cat([p.flatten() for p in model.parameters()])
print(params.shape) # torch.Size([31])
```

However, now modifying a parameter in `params` then does not change the actual model parameter (since `torch.cat()` copies the memory). **Is it possible to get a 1D tensor view of model parameters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by constructing the parameter tensor in 1d **first** and then copying views into the model:

```py
import torch

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(1, 10), 
    torch.nn.Tanh(), 
    torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)
)

def fuse_parameters(model):
    """Move model parameters to a contiguous tensor, and return that tensor."""
    n = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
    params = torch.zeros(n)
    i = 0
    for p in model.parameters():
        params_slice = params[i:i + p.numel()]
        params_slice.copy_(p.flatten())
        p.data = params_slice.view(p.shape)
        i += p.numel()
    return params

print("before fusing parameters")
with torch.no_grad(): print(model(torch.ones(3, 1)).flatten())
params = fuse_parameters(model)
print("after fusing parameters")
with torch.no_grad(): print(model(torch.ones(3, 1)).flatten());
params.mul_(2)
print("after modifying fused parameters")
with torch.no_grad(): print(model(torch.ones(3, 1)).flatten())
```

This prints:

```
before fusing parameters
tensor([-0.3356, -0.3356, -0.3356])
after fusing parameters
tensor([-0.3356, -0.3356, -0.3356])
after modifying fused parameters
tensor([-0.7728, -0.7728, -0.7728])
```

(Doing this kind of thing post-hoc - creating a single tensor view out of multiple different tensors - does not appear to be supported in PyTorch as of 2022-12. There's preliminary support for [nested tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nested.html), but the nested tensors still copy data.)

---

**If you also want to fuse grads**

You can do the same with gradients, and store the fused model gradients as a 1d tensor in `params.grad`

```py
import torch

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(1, 10), 
    torch.nn.Tanh(), 
    torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)
)

def fuse_parameters_and_gradients(model):
    """Move model parameters and gradients to a contiguous tensor, and return that tensor."""
    n = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
    params = torch.zeros(n, requires_grad=True)
    params.grad = torch.zeros(n)
    i = 0
    for p in model.parameters():
        params_slice = params[i:i + p.numel()]
        with torch.no_grad(): params_slice.copy_(p.flatten())
        p.data = params_slice.view(p.shape)
        p.grad = params.grad[i:i + p.numel()].view(p.shape)
        i += p.numel()
    return params

params = fuse_parameters_and_gradients(model)

print("params and grad before optimizer step")
with torch.no_grad(): print(params[:3], params.grad[:3])

opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 0.1)
opt.zero_grad(); model(torch.ones(1, 1)).backward(); opt.step()
print("\n(optimizer step)\n")

print("params and grad after optimizer step")
with torch.no_grad(): print(params[:3], params.grad[:3])
```

This prints:

```
params and grad before optimizer step
tensor([0.8219, 0.6089, 0.8708], requires_grad=True) tensor([0., 0., 0.])

(optimizer step)

params and grad after optimizer step
tensor([0.7974, 0.6136, 0.8743], requires_grad=True) tensor([ 0.2457, -0.0474, -0.0341])
```

Comment: This definitely answers my question. Do you know if it is possible for the fused parameters to also have the same gradient properties as the model parameters? So if I pass something through the model, it should update the gradients of the fused parameters too (and not just the original parameters).

Comment: I added a second version of the code that should fuse the grads as well (keeping their storage in `params.grad`)